# How to generate table without comma and bracket or get rid of those?

Tags: list-manipulation, output-formatting

I want just data without comma and brackets. Even `TableForm` is not working for me.
For example, the general pattern of my table is

```
t = Table[Table[{m, n}, {m, 1, 10}], {n, 1, 9}]
```

which gives output in the for `{x1,y1},{x2,y2}.....` . If I use `TableForm` it will show output as:

```
1 2 3  ... 10
1........... 
...............
2...Numbers......
..............
9............9
```

But I want output of just two columns for the values of m and n ({m,n}) like

```
m1 m2
m3 m4
.....
```

How to do that? Or suggest me how convert the data in the form {{x1,y1},{x2,y2}} in just two columns?

Comment: You've seen `Grid[]`?

Comment: Apart from the fine answers you've already gotten: `Flatten[Outer[Composition[Reverse, List], Range[5], Range[6]], 1] // Grid`

Comment: My answer was intended to be complementary to acl's.  The actual method in both answers is to use `Grid` after merging the top level of the array (with either `Faltten` or `Join`), and he posted first.  I am glad that you liked my answer but I would prefer that you accept his.  This is by no means required and you are always at liberty to Accept whatever answer you choose; it is simply my request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Join @@ Array[{#2, #} &, {5, 6}] // Grid

Tuples@Range@{5, 6} ~Reverse~ {2} // Grid
```

Comment: Or `Join @@ Transpose[Array[List, {6, 5}]] // Grid`

Answer (score 11):

```
t = Table[Table[{m, n}, {m, 1, 6}], {n, 1, 5}];
Flatten[t, 1] // Grid
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Some compaction can be done: `t = Table[{m, n}, {n, 1, 5}, {m, 1, 6}];`.

Comment: @J.M. & acl You both beat me by a few seconds - with the answer and the comment ;-)

Comment: @acl how can I export this grid to a .txt file. I need the data without the comas and bracets in the .txt file.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `Flatten` should work. If you have, e.g. a List like `{{a, b}, {c, {d}, e}, {f, {g, h}}}`, as a result of a `Table[]` or something else, using `Flatten[{{a, b}, {c, {d}, e}, {f, {g, h}}}]` you obtain `{a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h}`.